# Jquery-ui datepicker in angualar directive - beforeShowDay issue

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, asynchronous, angularjs-directive, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've build directive for jquery datepicker.
my problem starts when the user click on next month action.

The calendar starts with highlight on some days - list which come from the server and when the user clicks on next month the calendar is not rendered with the highlighted days.
Each click on the next/previous month I call to the server for new days list with highlight icons.

The problem is that the calendar displaying/initialized before the request to server completed.

There is my code:

```
  app.directive('calanderD', function($timeout, $window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'calanderDTemplate.html',
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            fn: '&'
        },
        controller: function($scope, $element, $q) {

            $scope.date_format = 'dd-mm-yyyy';
            $scope.fetchHighligtedDays = function(date) {

               $scope.data.days = here is the server call...
               ..
            };

             $scope.getHighligthedDays = function(date) {
                var flag = false;
                if ($scope.data.days.length) {
                    for (var idx in $scope.data.days) {
                        if ($scope.data.days[idx].date === date) {
                            if ($scope.data.days[idx].highlight === 'true'){
                                flag = true;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return flag;
            };
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            if (scope.data) {

                scope.dateOptions = {
                    showOn: "button",
                    buttonImage: "pics/datepicker.png",
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    showOtherMonths: true,

                    changeMonth: false,
                    changeYear: false,
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    buttonText: '',
                    prevText: '',
                    nextText: '',

                    firstDay: 1,   
                    dateFormat: scope.date_format,


                    beforeShowDay: function(dateToBeRendered) {

                        var isHighlight = scope.getHighligthedDays(dateToBeRendered);
                        if (isHighlight) {

                           // do style stuff here
                           ...
                        }
                        return [true, 'highlight-style','')];
                    },

                    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
                        var date = new Date(year, month);
                        scope.fetchMontlyAlerts(date);
                    }
                };
            }

        }
    };
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you not just cache all the data when the page loads?  Seems crazy to be making all those ajax calls.  Can't be that much data.

Comment: No, can't cache all the data.. need to do it that way..

Comment: is your data stored in $scope.data.days ?

Comment: yes. that data is per month..

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution would just be to keep the calendar hidden until the data is available.
(pseudo-code):

```
if ($scope.data.days) {
show = true
}
```

When they click the next or prev month button add `$scope.data.days = ''`to the function just before the ajax call

You could alternatively (this may be a better idea too) set the `show` variable in the successfully returned promise function of the ajax call.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it's does not work like that.
jquery ui datepicker has beforeShowYear event which is fired after onChangeMonthYear event..
The problem is that the service call is invoked from onChangeMonthYear -  and since all the requests in angular are by default are Asynchronous calls - the bebeforeShowYear event is invoked before we have the data that comes from onChangeMonthYear event..

Comment: Can you set up a plunker?

Comment: Hmm. Can't you just mock some http requests with a timeout and some data?